# What is a Popsplit and how can I do it (agar.io)?

Tags: agar.io

There are so many Youtube videos about doing Popsplits in Agar.io.

I don't get it, how is this working? I hope somebody can tell me exactly how Popsplits work and how I can do it.

An example video:

Comment: Is it allowed to upload a YouTube video? I've seen links to the videos, but direct link? That video has gained lots of views for nothing. It is not even relevant to the question that much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You popsplit by splitting twice into an enemy within range of a virus:

`(sqrt(opponent's mass + your mass/4)-sqrt(opponent's mass))/pi mass distance`

In other words, the opponent needs to be big enough to hit the virus after consuming one of your pieces. I'd recommend using a macro (see: ogar) and popsplitting enemies slightly larger than half your size (preferably within 8% of a difference.)

Ogar can be downloaded [here](http://ogario.ovh).

Comment: Yea. This is probably the right answer

Comment: So if I understand you correctly: You intentionally feed half of your mass to an opponent so they grow into a nearby virus, they get split up in many smal fragments and you then eat those up?

Comment: That is correct @Phillip!